# Javascript: Why am I able to access Function.prototype.call without mentioning the prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, function-binding

Here is a snippet to explain my question:

```
+function(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[a-z]|\s[a-z]/g,
            Function.call.bind(String.prototype.toUpperCase));
}('foo bar baz.');  //Returns Foo Bar Baz.
```

`Function.call` works, but `String.toUpperCase` does not. I have to instead write, `String.prototype.toUpperCase`.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-18/code-snippets-and-in-the-darkness-bind-them/

Comment: Pointy's answer below is perfectly right. Note that this is still a roundabout way of accessing `call`, so please don't do this in actual code =p

Comment: @Kyll Yes, this was just an experiment. I cannot accept the answer yet! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Function()` constructor is itself a function. Therefore, it inherits from the same prototype object as any other function.

Instances of `String()` inherit from the prototype, but the `String()` constructor is *not* an instance of `String()`. It too is a function.